# Efficient ActiveRecord has_and_belongs_to_many query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have Page and Paragraph models with a has_and_belongs_to_many relation. Given a paragraph_id, I'd like to get all matching pages. e.g.:

```
pages = Paragraph.find(paragraph_id).pages.all
```

However, this takes two queries. It can be done in one query:

```
SELECT "pages".* FROM "pages" 
INNER JOIN "pages_paragraphs" ON "pages_paragraphs"."page_id" = "pages"."id" 
WHERE "pages_paragraphs"."paragraph_id" = 123
```

But can this be done without

- using find_by_sql
- without modifications to the page_paragraphs table (e.g. adding an id).

Update:

My page model looks like this:

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :paragraphs, uniq: true
end
```

Comment: @jdoe I've clarified my question, thanks for your efforts.

Comment: What is the issue with two queries? Is there a more complicated example you are trying to optimize that we aren't seeing?

Comment: No, I just want to execute the SQL in my question with an activerecord query.

Answer (score 22):

**With a has_many :through relationship, you could use this:**

```
pages = Page.joins(:pages_paragraphs).where(:pages_paragraphs => {:paragraph_id => 1})
```

Take a look at *Specifying Conditions on the Joined Tables* here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

If you want the pages and paragraphs together:

```
pages = Page.joins(:pages_paragraphs => :paragraph).includes(:pages_paragraphs => :paragraph).where(:pages_paragraphs => {:paragraph_id => 1})
```

**With a has_and_belongs_to_many:**

```
pages = Page.joins("join pages_paragraphs on pages.id = pages_paragraphs.page_id").where(["pages_paragraphs.paragraph_id = ?", paragraph_id])
```

Comment: `Association named 'pages_paragraphs' was not found`

Comment: Without the a model/association for your pages_paragraphs table, you can do the join conditions as strings.  Page.joins("join pages_paragraphs on pages_paragraphs.page_id = pages.id").where("pages_paragraphs.paragraph_id = ?", paragraph_id)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `eager_load` for this

```
pages = Paragraph.eager_load(:pages).find(paragraph_id).pages
```

I found an article all about this sort of thing:
[3 ways to do eager loading (preloading) in Rails 3 & 4](http://blog.arkency.com/2013/12/rails4-preloading/) by [Robert Pankowecki](http://blog.arkency.com/by/pankowecki/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `includes` for this :

`pages = Paragraph.includes(:pages).find(paragraph_id).pages`

Comment: `includes` uses an extra query to load related data. The OP asked for the whole thing in one query, so this doesn't work.